# c, assigning value pointed to by void * to void * array

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am trying to assign a value pointed at by a `void *` in a `void *` array. Here is what I have so far:

```
23 void queue_enqueue(void *q, void *item) {
24 int len = 0 ;
25 
26 len = sizeof(q) ;
27 q[len-1] = 
28     item ;
29     
30 return ;
31 
32 }
```

With this compiler error:

```
myqueue.c:27: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
myqueue.c:28: error: invalid use of void expression
```

I've been searching for an answer for about a hour now, but I haven't seen an implementation similar to what I have been given here. In case you were wondering, yes this is homework and the prototype was given by the instructor.

Because they are passed as void * I have been unable to use the gcc `typeof` operator.

I'm okay with the warning. I know it's just gcc telling me that "be careful we're not going to check this for you", but I can't get rid of the error on line 28.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Do you know that `sizeof` gives you the size of the pointer, and not the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @Calvin - I am creating a queue and to eliminate data redundancy I am allowing it to hold any data type

Comment: @asaeir - You're completely right. You just saved me some time trying to track down that bug.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an array of `void*`s, it's an array of `void` (which doesn't really exist), and dereferencing it gets you a `void`, which is "not a real type", so you can't assign to it.

If you're trying to work with an array of `void*`, change it to

```
void queue_enqueue(void** q, void* item)
```

or

```
void queue_enqueue(void* q[], void* item) // same as above
```

Also realise that your program will do

```
q[sizeof(void**) - 1] = item;
```

every time. `sizeof` gives you the size of the pointer type, not the array. You have to pass the length of an array as a separate argument if you want to know how long an array is.

Comment: When using: 
    char * c ; 
    c = malloc(10) ;
 
You are able to access individual elements. I created as such:

    void * myqueue ;
    myqueue = (void **)malloc( n ) ; 

And thought that I would be able to access each individual element as I would with an array. The professor gave us the following .h file (which we must use).:

    void *queue_new(int numItems);  
    void queue_enqueue(void *q, void *item);
    void *queue_dequeue(void *q); 
    int queue_isEmpty(void *q);

Comment: @user1042739 those are really dubious function prototypes; for instance, how are you supposed to know if a queue is empty with just a pointer? I would ask your professor for more details on how this is supposed to work. Also, you can't do `(void**)malloc(n)` because that makes it a pointer of pointers to `void`, which will screw your data up if they are e.g. `char`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of `void*`:

```
void queue_enqueue(void *q[], void *item)
```

Answer (score 0):

void is a type with no size.
Thus an array of void cannot exist. (because an array defines the amount of units and then jumps using the sizeof() operator.

you would have to cast the void* to something*, something having the same size of what you actually have stored there, so say you have type T, which is of same SIZE( I'm not saying same thing ),

```
T* q2 = (T*)q;
T* item2 = (T*)item;
q2[len-1] = &item;
```

This will work because C passes pointers by reference.
since T will be a real type the compiler lets you do it
since T is same size as your actual stored values, you will wind up with the correct value storage location.

note that void* as an array, will contain a pointer to an array of type void.
void* as a single value will contain a single value of void.

Comment: Also, for the lenght, use:  
len = sizeof(&q)/sizeof(T);